# outlet not working but grounding screw is hot

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've got a non-working outlet that I can't seem to fix.

It's got two black wires, two white wires, and no ground wire.

I bought a new outlet (shown) and attached the black wires to the screws on the right, and the white ones to the screws on the left. (I didn't understand why there were two of each kind of wire, but read on this board that that's not uncommon. I still don't understand why there is no ground wire.)

When I turn the circuit back on, the outlet does not work, and I detect no current in either the hot side or the neutral side. BUT the ground screw IS hot. Yet as i say there is no ground wire to attach.

This is a weird circuit, tied in to a dishwasher and another light. The light works when the circuit is on, but the outlet and dishwasher do not. An appliance guy said he was getting current on the hot wire on the dishwasher, but not the neutral wire, and thought replacing this broken outlet would fix things. But I can't make the outlet work.

[image]

Advice?

---

[image]

The original outlet. It was installed upside down; I shifted the black and white wires in order to install the new one in the normal orientation. (Maybe that matters?)

I learned the outlet was hot by accident. Assuming it was all dead (having tested the black and neutral wires and screws with a two-pronged voltage detector, and since the outlet wasn't functional), I started to screw it in before seeking help here or from an electrician. There was a significant spark. I then used the voltage tester on the ground screw, and the light went on.

Despite the tile, this is nowhere near water; it's decorative tile on the opposite side of the kitchen from the sink.

---

Original box, showing the two black and two white wires. AS mentioned, the previous outlet was installed upside down, with black on the left and white on the right. No evident ground wire.

[image]

Comment: What are you using to test the ground screw and determine it is hot? For what you have shown us here, that should be impossible. If you are measuring it correctly, then the only way you would read hot on the ground screw in this configuration is if the HOT wire is sheathing damaged and touching the metal box, or if you are not using a proper neutral and the ground (through the box) is working. Please disassemble the wires from this outlet immediately. Do not reconnect them until you can determine the proper hot and neutral wires. You currently have a fire hazard risk.

Comment: With the wires all disconnected, take a photo of the inside of the box and the wires, and tell us what was determined as HOT. We will also have to determine which wires are switched hot (for the light), and then if the whites are actually both neutrals. They may not be. Also, please share a photo of the old outlet.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the actual insides of the box?

Comment: Also, is this circuit protected by a GFCI? Looking at the picture you've provided (with Tile), it should be

Comment: How was it wired before with the broken outlet? Daisy chains are common and the box being metal could be the ground.

Comment: Apologies for the slow response. I've attached a photo of the box, without outlet. I "tested" the ground screw first by accident: In screwing in what I assumed was a dead outlet into the wall, so I could go consult a forum or an electrician, there was a spark. I then used an entry-level two-prong voltage detector, and found that the black and white wires were cold, but the ground screw was hot.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite

It's not metal conduit, those are Romex clamps.

The first problem is that you have power on the receptacle somewhere when you expect not to.  So keep using that voltage tester.  There are lots of ways to use a voltage tester wrong, but this for sure: it should never light up on a dead circuit. if you have turned the circuit off, and it is not dead, it is now very important to find out which *other* breaker you must turn off to make it actually dead.  It's likely these two breakers together form a *multi-wire branch circuit*, which share a neutral in an engineered way which works. However there are certain rules MWBCs must follow, and if they do not, they become nightmares, with symptoms like these.   We need to know if 2 breakers feed that circuit so we can work that issue... if it's an issue.

Looking at that melted neutral, it would also matter to know exactly where in the service panel those two breakers are.   That super matters.

It would also be good to know if this installer was habitually using white for hot and black for neutral. (Maybe he was British?)

It would also be good to get a length of wire so you can get a reliable ground from some place like a sink, spigot, water pipe etc.

Aside from that,  screws shorting against the metal box could contribute to the problem.  Wrap the receptacle with tape edgewise to stop that from happening.

Comment: Unless I'm off base in some obvious area (and I dont believe I am) everyone is ignoring or missing the OP said the ground screw is hot. I'm willing to bet this is not accurate, because **IF** it is, then the box **HAS** to be hot as well, if it was grounded, the breaker **SHOULD** pop. Since it isn't, **IF** the box **IS** hot, the outlet "would" be working, but OP says it is not. So one must presume the outlet is DOA, or the NEUTRAL shown is not neutral. (although the neutral does look a bit melted).

Comment: I think people are skeptical of his claim since he hasn't  described the testing method by which he reached that conclusion.  I for one suspect a magic 8-ball (the legends on a 3-lamp tester) was involved.

Comment: I fully agree @Harper,  but these  answers can't be right.  The outlet would be working as pictured.  So we need answers to quite  a few questions before we note answers

Comment: It was not a three-lamp tester, but a voltage detector. (Apologies for the scattered responses; still learning the ropes on this forum.)

Comment: Ok good, so you can reproduce this with the voltage detector.  I would turn off one breaker at a time (or several at once and narrow it down) to see which breaker(s) must be on for the ground screw to be hot. Also test if any other screws on other switches or receptacles are hot when this one is.   Start with the one for this circuit.  If it's the breaker for *this* circuit, try the "wrap with tape" option and see if it goes away.

Comment: @Harper, I don't quite follow. I know what circuit this outlet is on (and I've turned it off, for safety). Are you saying other circuits could affect the performance of this one? I will try the tape option, however, and the shear-the-screws options mentioned by others.

Comment: @C.Shea Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  It's common, especially in dishwasher circuits, to double up circuits.  Bottom line if anything is hot when the breaker is off, another circuit must be interacting and we need to know which.

Comment: @Harper Ok, makes sense. As far as I know, nothing is hot when this circuit is turned off. Apologies if my description was unclear on this point.

Comment: @C.Shea ok well that's good, if we can exclude MwBCs this gets simpler.  I'd start with checking the panel and every other receptacle on the circuit to see if he used black for neutral/white for hot.  You can't fix the lack of ground but you can put a GFCI on it and not care.

Comment: Wrapped with tape and something is still amiss. Plug doesn't work, but pushing the outlet into the box produces a spark and a receptacle meter (the three-light thing) shows either an "open ground" or all lights on. Seems unsafe. Will check the other things you recommend.

Comment: looking at your first photo I see bare wire exposed even with the wire under the screw.  Get some electrical tape and wrap that.  That may be your problem.  You can also look for signs of arcing or sputtering on wires or box.

Comment: Everything makes sense now! nice rewrite too. Nice job on clarifications and updates to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Is the grounding screw "hot" when the new outlet is shoved up in the electrical box and screwed in? If so one of the screws for the black wires or one of the black wires themselves is most likely shorted to the electrical box. The screw could be touching or the black wire could have a bare part or break in the insulation.

The reason that you see two sets of blacks/whites on an outlet like this is that one set feeds in power from upstream and the other set branches out to some other part of the circuit downstream. The outlet doubles as a joining block to bridge the black to black and the white to white.

Comment: I think we need more information to make this determination. The neutral or the hot for the downstream circuit could be connected elsewhere and not even in this box while a portion of the outlet could have been switched, even along with the light. I mean, if the hot is shorted to ground, and the ground was true, then the circuit breaker should pop and or the light would not be working. Also, If the ground is not true, the outlet would be working

Comment: OP says there is no ground in the box. This is why this box could be hot and not pop the circuit breaker.

Comment: then as wired, the outlet would be working.

Comment: And while there is a statement of no ground in box, the box itself could have been grounded (while it probably isn't) we dont know without more pictures. Also, no grounds means this box is already a hack, or split off a 240. (This is why on other topics on the site I despise split 240's), we just don't know enough for this to be the answer (yet) and it certainly doesn't explain why the outlet doesn't work

Comment: @noybman multi-wire branch circuits? You just need to get to know them.  They are actually efficient and rather handy, except for the GFCi facfor, and that only bothers me becaise I dislike GFCI receptacles.

Comment: @Harper,  not sure what you're getting at.  The outlet would still be working as pictured.  No reason to dislike gfci's, they do their job well.

Comment: @nobyman "multi-wire branch circuit" is the formal name for the type of circuit you said you despise.  As for GFCIs I only dislike the kind which are also receptacles,  because they are a magnet for stupidity.  Deadfaces and breakers I'm fine with.

Comment: Yes, the ground screw was hot when the outlet was screwed in tightly. I have not tested it otherwise, though I could.

Comment: (Correction, I LEARNED it was hot while screwing it in, then stopped. It tested as hot while not screwed in.)

Comment: @Harper, yes, I know what mwbc is, what I meant by "I don't know what you are getting at" was because if this was a mwbc, the rules still apply, so the answer posted in this portion of the thread doesn't hold water.